# Translating Prototype to jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, prototypejs

What would be the jQuery equivalent to this Prototype snippet?

```
if ($('recent_forum_topics') != undefined) {
    new Ajax.Updater({
        success: 'recent_forum_topics'
    },
    '/welcome/recent_forum_topics');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even simpler, [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load):

```
$('#recent_forum_topics').load('/welcome/recent_forum_topics');
```

Comment: +1 People often are unaware that methods applied to the object set apply like a for-each generally, so if the selector returns no objects, it just does nothing - so no need for the separate check.

Comment: You gotta love how jQuery is much simpler than Prototype.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that recent_forum_topics is the div id.

```
if ($('#recent_forum_topics').length) {
  $.ajax({
      url: '/welcome/recent_forum_topics',
      success: function(data) {
        $('#recent_forum_topics').html(data);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt Ball! i forgot the length property.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest version is in my opinion:

```
$('#recent_forum_topics').load('/welcome/recent_forum_topics');
```

Comment: The `if(...length)` check is completely unnecessary.